# How implement Pathfinding in LibGDX-AI >1.8.0

Tags: java, libgdx, artificial-intelligence, path-finding

I try to do a Zelda style game , I would like the monsters to walk chaotic, and after approaching the player at a certain distance they start looking for a way to him. For this I need pathfinding. I found a movie on YT and tried to implement this solution in my project, but practically nothing works.
In the given tutorial after calling the resultPath.getCount() method you get the way to the hero, in my case this number equals 0 and increases by 1 after each call. The same node is added over and over again.

Size: 1, : GraphPathImp{nodes=[Node{index=0, tileX=7, tileY=3}]}
Size: 2, : GraphPathImp{nodes=[Node{index=0, tileX=7, tileY=3}, Node{index=0, tileX=7, tileY=3}]}
Size: 3, : GraphPathImp{nodes=[Node{index=0, tileX=7, tileY=3}, Node{index=0, tileX=7, tileY=3}, Node{index=0, tileX=7, tileY=3}]}
...

Project repo: https://github.com/DMizyn/rpg
YT video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wu3vzR9k3QA

It would be great if someone looked at my repo :)
I want someone to check if I have implemented GraphPathImp, GraphImp and Node correctly.
I suspect that the errors result from removing DefaultIndexedGraph and IndexedNode in libGDX-AI 1.8.0 and I can't recreate it in my project.

I don't understand why the same Node is added over and over again.

LibGDX 1.9.8
LibGDX-ai 1.8.1